# Selecting Data from Normalized Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I'm stuck on trying to write this query, I think my brain is just a little fried tonight. I have this table that stores whenever a person executes an action (Clocking In, Clocking Out, Going on Lunch, Returning from Lunch) and I need to return a list of all the primary ID's for the people who's last action is not clock_out - but the problem is it needs to be a somewhat fast query.

Table Structure:

```
ID | person_id | status | datetime | shift_type
```

ID = Primary Key for this table

person_id = The ID I want to return if their status does not equal clock_out

status = clock_in, lunch_start, lunch_end, break_start, break_end, clock_out

datetime = The time the record was added

shift_type = Not Important

The way I was executing this query before was finding people who are still clocked in during a specific time period, however I need this query to locate at any point. The queries I am trying are taking the thousands and thousands of records and making it way too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through it further, this was my solution -

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT `status`,`person_id` FROM `timeclock` ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
) AS tmp_table GROUP BY `person_id`
```

This works because it is grouping all of the same person ID's together, and then ordering them by the datetime and selecting the most recent.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to return a list of all the primary ID's for the people whose last action is not clock_out.

One option uses window functions, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select id
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by person_id order by datetime desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1 and status <> 'clock_out'
```

In earlier versions, one option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select id
from mytable 
where 
    datetime = (select max(t1.datetime) from mytable t1 where t1.personid = t.person_id)
    and status <> 'clock_out'
```

Comment: I'm not sure the hosting server is running on windows though

Comment: "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting FOR, LOCK, TABLE, VALUES, WITH, '('

Comment: @JayMason: [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) have nothing to do with Windows (the operating system). However, they are available in MySQ. 8.0 only; which version are you running?

Comment: MySQL Server 8.0 , MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: @JayMason: ok, so this will work. Please run the query exactly as provided.

Comment: I'm Sorry @GMB I can't use this. My hosting server is using version 5.6.41-84.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222115/discussion-between-jay-mason-and-gmb).